# Picking points inside a sphere

Tags: geometric-probability

How to solve it?

"Suppose that $N$ points are independently chosen at random inside a sphere of radius $R$. Find the probability of the distance between the center of the sphere and the closest point being greater than $r$, $r < R$, assuming the points are evenly distributed inside the sphere."

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Closest point is further than $r\Longrightarrow$ all points are further. Now evaluate the volumes

Comment: I don't even understand the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the probability that a specific point is at distance larger than $r$ from the center?

It is clearly $1-(\frac{r}{R})^3$. You want the probability that this happens for all of the points.

Since the points are chosen independently the probability is $(1-(\frac{r}{R})^3)^N$

Comment: How come? Is $(\frac{r}{R})^3$ the probability of the distance between a point and the center being less than $r$? Why? I don't understand your approach.

Comment: yes, that's exactly it. Why? The volume of the sphere of radius $r$ is $\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$ and the volume of the sphere with radius $R$ is $\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$. The ratio between the volumes if $(\frac{r}{R})^3$. So if you pick a point inside the big sphere, the probability that is inside the small sphere is $(\frac{r}{R})^3$